# Maven JAX-RS tutorial issues

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am brand new to maven, JAX-RS and the entire Jave EE environment.  I was going through this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs003.htm#GIPZZ) to get a simple web app up and running but I am having problems running out of the gate.  After I finish simply create the project (as step 1.e suggests) I get a maven error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Archetype org.meruvian.yama:yama-jaxrs-archetype:1.0.3 is not configured
Property databaseUrl is missing.
Property databaseUsername is missing.
Property databasePassword is missing.
```

I am running JDK7u49 and the NetBeans IDE 7.4.

I've found people with somewhat similar errors but they are much far along and broke an existing environment.  As this is a BRAND NEW environment, I'm guessing I am not setting something up correctly.  Though this tutorial suggests my local machine will accept a web request on port 8080, yet they never go through the configuration of a web server.  Am I missing something big here?

Comment: So you click finish in NetBeans and see this error? The error suggests the credentials for the Java DB database are missing. Nothing to do with a web server. Have you tried with Maven proper from the command line?

Comment: Why is it looking for DB creds?  All I am doing is just setting up the framework for a new project, right?  Does it assume I have all of the backend infrastructure ready for a web app?  If so, why does it assume I have a DB?  I don't necessarily need a DB to have a web service....

Comment: That's true. However, the archetype might produce a project that demonstrates web services with the help of a database. I don't use NetBeans but tried the same thing in my IDE (IntelliJ) and didn't even get as far as you. I get "The defined artifact is not an archetype."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the tutorial doesn't work because the original archetype is missing.

The best way to start with JAX-RS would be to start a new project under NetBeans in the **Samples->Web Services** section, picking everything that starts with "**REST**".

Or you can do this to start brand new:

1. **New Project->Maven->Web Application**
2. **New File->Web Services->RESTful web services from patterns**

Comment: New Project->Maven->Web Application is not an option using my IDE or the JDK.  Know what I might be missing?  Sorry, I'm very new to this and there doesn't seem to be one place that has all of this info....

Comment: For JAX-RS in NetBeans, you need the Java EE edition. Look for Java EE in [https://netbeans.org/downloads/](https://netbeans.org/downloads/).

Comment: Say you go in the menu File->New Project there is a Maven section there?

Comment: Downloading the JavaEE ONLY version enabled that feature, even though the FULL version supposedly had everything.